# Clean certain entries in DB through collection

Tags: magento-1.7, database, collection, resource-model

I searched for a way to clean rows in DB, where *something*, through a resource collection call, but could not find relevant information.

I.e., I have table with fields **store_id , path , value** and 400 rows and I want to clean the rows where the *store_id* is 1 (or something else). My question is - is this possible through a collection call, or with the resource model?

The table is custom, and I have resource model for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('[namespace]/[module]')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

**[EDIT]**
An alternative is to add this method in your resource model (not collection model, just resource).

```
public function deleteByStoreId($storeId) {
    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $condition = array(
        'store_id = ?'     => $storeId,
    );
    $adapter->delete($this->getMainTable(), $condition);
    return $this;
}
```

and then just call

```
Mage::getResourceModel('[namespace]/[module]')->deleteByStoreId();
```

of course this is just an example. You can make a general delete method so you can pass as many filters as you want.

Comment: Yeah, but this might take time if there are more entries. Isn't there a way to delete multiple entries at one time. Something like `$model = Mage::getModel('[module]/[model]')->getResource()->addFieldToFilter($scopeId);` and then `$model->delete();`

Comment: @Syspect. See my update. Maybe that helps.